# Number of ways to choose a composition of $n$ and then color each odd part either red or blue

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $h_n$ be the number of ways to choose a composition of $n$ and then color each odd part either red or blue. For instance, when $n=3$ we have the following compositions
\begin{align}
3& & 2+1 & & 1+2 & & 1+1+1
\end{align}
we can color the first one, the second one, and the third one in $2$ ways, and the last one in $2(3)=8$ ways, so $h_3=14$. Determine the generating function and find a closed-form formula for $h_n$.

---

I know this involves composition of generating functions. I was thinking that if $a_n$ is the number of ways to choose a composition of $n$, with generating function $A(x)$ and $b_n$ the number of ways to color each composition of $n$, with generating function $B(x)$, the generating function $H(x)$ of $h_n$ would be
\begin{equation}
H(x)=B(A(x)).
\end{equation}
I also know that the number of compositions of $n$ is $a_n=2^{n-1}$, thus $A(x)=\frac{x}{1-2x}$. The problem now is finding $b_n$, and this is where I'm having trouble, since for any $n$ I have to count the number of odd elements of each $k$ composition of $n$  and if the number is, say, $p_k$, then $b_n=\sum_{k= 0}^n2^{p_k}$. How can I calculate $p_k$?

Is my approach the appropriate one for this type of problem or am I missing something? Any ideas or hints are gladly appreciated. :)

Comment: For , $n=3$ if you make partition then the second and the third are equivalent

Comment: @SalmonFish sure, but the problem asks for compositions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568672/a-question-on-composition-of-generating-functions